# How to connect firebase in android studio 3.0 and store the data in real time database by press button

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to learn about firebase in android so how can I connect the firebase in android latest version 3.0 and store the data in real time database in my firebase project can anyone help me ....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. If you had done so, you'd know that the [help/on-topic] guidelines very clearly say you can't ask us to find a tutorial or other off-site resource. Please do that reading before posting your next question here.

Comment: sorry for that sir @Ken White sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be provided with plugins when you create a new project in firebase. You have to paste it in Android studio inside gradle file.

For full reference check this link, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVu_xSzn2u0&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcTXrWuRTa59RyRmQ4OedWrt&index=2

Youtube Channel - TVAC might help you out